# Java Spring Batch - MultiResourceItemReader not reading in new files every job run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working to get a spring batch application running that checks for new .txt files on a network drive on a scheduler. The intention is to read in those .txt files, grab the information off of them, process them, and then delete the original .txt file that was read. The issue I'm running into is that it keeps reading the same resource even after the resource is deleted.

Subsequently this causes the next job to use the same exact resource again. Something else I noticed was that it reads in the files before the first job even runs.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong with spring batch? Is it not possible to do something like this:
`multiResourceItemReader.setResources(getNetworkFiles())`

So that every job it goes and reads in the files from the network drive?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the `getNetworkFiles()` call I mentioned was annotated as a @Bean and it turns out it should not have been. Removing that got it to re-read from the network drive directory.